# What's the latest on HTML Email best practice?

Tags: html, html-email

I've been asked to build something that will generate HTML Emails.

The last time I created one of these was about three years ago, and so I was wondering if the warnings about using tables, nested tables, having to use inline stylesheets etc. still had to be heeded, or whether (hopefully) email clients had caught up a bit with browsers, and would allow use of external stylesheets, divs and so forth.

I did have a good Google for info, but most articles I found were a few years old, and so was wondering what the current state of play was.

Can anyone update me on the latest best practice?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We recently put together an HTML email. We learn't the following:

- There is HUGE disparity in HTML and CSS support in modern and older clients alike. And mostly that support is pretty terrible.
- Do not use external or header CSS. Inline EVERYTHING.
- Use tables for layout. Nested tables I think are ok, we didn't see any problems with this.
- Use a service like [Email-on-Acid](http://www.emailonacid.com/) to check how your mail renders in different clients.
- Making something that looks nice and polished across the major clients is a gigantic pain and will take you 5 times longer than you imagine.
- In short, nothing's changed in the last 3 years.

Good luck!

Comment: if you do want to use css, you have to put the style region inside the body tag, and then you have to put everything inside a container to apply the things you would normally do on the body.

Comment: @Luke: this has very variable support across different clients. It's best to mark up every single element with inline css.

Comment: "Making something that looks nice and polished across the major clients is a gigantic pain and will take you 5 times longer than you imagine." - Indeed. :) Inline CSS was definitely the way forwrad, since Google mail seemed to strip out anything inside a <style> tag.

Answer (score 1):

*Don't use HTML email.*

...if you have the choice. However, seeing as you've been asked to use HTML email, here are a few things I can think of. Mail clients like Thunderbird have improved their HTML support a lot lately, but it's still unreliable, especially given the not-so-modern clients floating around.

- keep your email content as simple as possible
- make sure that it looks alright without images; most email clients disable image rendering until told to do otherwise for each message

Comment: Thanks Delan! Apologies for delay in responding. I completely agree with your sentiments re: HTML emails :)